# When is it best to use a python map function with a user defined function with parentheses or without parentheses

Tags: python

Sorry if this sound like a dumb question, I really do not understand why am i getting values back and why the complier is not screaming error, first the below code  the function add_to_five receive an (x) in the (parentheses) and return the value of x + 5; however when called in the map function i only pass in add_to_five without parentheses and provided a iterable sequence of l for the second arg and the new_value is [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

how is x getting assigned, when called in the the map the add_to_five clearly does not get the parentheses explicitly assigned and the value of (x) is not provided to the function, however some how l is been replaced into the parentheses of add_to_five that why the result is [6, 7, 8, 9, 10].

when i take away (x +) in the return and just return only 5 though still left an (x) in the parentheses of add_to_five the new_value become [5,5,5,5,5] and i do not get an error when add_to_five referenced in the map function.

why does add_to_five work in the map function with out parentheses and also worked when i returned just (5) and still leave the (x) in the parentheses with out binding (x) to anything or value (5).

when is it best to use a function with parentheses as i know when invoked (type of add_to_five(5)) it return (int) as object type and when invoked (type of add_to_five) it returns function and random memory address.

I know lambda is a way to work around but not looking for quick solution thank you.

```
def add_to_five(x):

        return x + 5
 
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

new_value = list(map(add_to_five, l))
print(new_value)
```

Comment: `map(function, iterable)`  ... you supply the function by its name. adding () after a functions name executes/calls it - this is what map does on every element of your iterable - thats what _map_ does. Whats not clear about that?

Comment: You just need to pass the function name, actual call takes place inside `map` under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about functions in Python as simply objects. Objects can be passed to functions and also can be returned from functions. This is actually *functional-style programming*.

In your `map` function, you pass in a function and a list or any other object/collection that can be iterated.
Why you don't include the parantheses is because it is **not a function call**.
You'll always hear variables store data or references to data. But here the variable actually holds a reference to code.
When you create a function:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
        ...
```

`func` is a function object. It is a variable that holds a reference to the code that is contained within the function.
If I do:

```
x = func
```

Here I have not used parantheses even though `func` is a function.
I can now do this:

```
x(1, 2)
```

It is because I assigned `x` as `func`. Calling `x` is equivalent to calling `func`.

This is a **simplified** form of how the map function works:

```
def map(function_to_call, iterable):
     result = []
     for element in iterable:
         r = function_to_call(element)
         result.append(r)
   return result
```

Now I can go ahead and call map like this:

```
def square(x):
     return x * x

map(square, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

**Map function does not return a list, it returns a map object that can be converted to a list.** Here I have simplified it to prevent distraction.
So `map` takes in a function and a sequence, iterates over that sequence and calls the passed function on each and every element and creates a new sequence that contains the results. Map only takes a reference to the function so that it can call that function later during execution.

`add_to_five` similarly is a function object. It is passed to `map` so that `map` can call it later multiple times for each element.

This is advanced, so the confusion is common.
Hope this helps, let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps explaining it:

Map is a function by it self, like any other function you provide the parameters for the function in (parentheses) and seperated by comma. Map works the same, only difference is that you do not insert an integer or string but a function, see here:

```
def add_to_five(x):

        return x + 5

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def map_function(a_function, lst):
    for i, element in enumerate(lst):
        lst[i] = a_function(element)
    return lst

print(map_function(add_to_five, l))
#[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: thank you. Unlike Partrick because he programming for 30 year he think everyone has his knowledge.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answers your question can you  mark it as accepted answer? Happy coding!